# Escape charaters in JSON causing issue while retrieving attribute in ForEach activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have below JSON

```
{
             "id": " https://xxx.vault.azure.net/secrets/xxx ",
             "attributes": {
                 "enabled": true,
                 "nbf": 1632075242,
                 "created": 1632075247,
                 "updated": 1632075247,
                 "recoveryLevel": "Recoverable+Purgeable"
             },
             "tags": {}
}
```

The above JSON is the output of a web activity and I am using this output into a ForEach activity. The above output when goes to ForEach activity as input, all the values are coming with escape characters.

{

{"id":" https://xxx.vault.azure.net/secrets/xxx ","attributes":{"enabled":true,"nbf":1632075242,"created":1632075247,"updated":1632075247,"recoveryLevel":"Recoverable+Purgeable"},"tags":{}}

From this JSON, I am trying to get only xxx value from the id attribute. How can I do this in Dynamic expression.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask why you are sending it to a For Each loop if you only want one value?  Is the real JSON more complicated or will it have many id values?  If so, please provide an example with at least two id attributes as this will have a bearing on the solution.

Comment: @wBob... i gave one in my example for illustration, but I have many Id values. I am already able to resolve the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in functions `lastIndexOf` (to find the last occurence of backslash), `length` (to determine the length of a string), `add` (to add numbers), `sub` (to subtract numbers) and `substring` to do this.  For example:

```
@substring(item().id,add(lastIndexOf(item().id,'/'),1),sub(length(item().id),add(lastIndexOf(item().id,'/'),1)))
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution worked

Comment: I used this which is recommended by someone on another platform.                                                        @substring(item().id,add(lastindexof(item().id,'/'),1),sub(length(item().id),add(lastindexof(item().id,'/'),1)))